.NET Core userManager failing CreateAsync on an apostrophe
I seem to be failing on the CreateAsync call for the UserManager in my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API controller.
var user = new AppUser
        {
            DisplayName = "Bob O'Donnell",
            Email = "bob.o'donnell@mydomain.mil",
            UserName = "bob.o'donnell@mydomain.mil"
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerDTO.Password);

I'm guessing the apostrophe is causing issues?
Here is where I am setting up the UserManager:
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
{
    opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    opt.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
  .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Do I need to add something to this configuration to allow the apostrophe?

i do curious whether bob.o'donnell@mydomain.mil is a valid e-mail? "I seem to be failing on the CreateAsync" - does it throw exceptions? is the user added into the table in the database?

It is a valid email its from office 365 tenant. Its not added to the identity db table looking at sql server. I added some logging so hopefully can see the actual exception tommorow

thank you, i learned something new that the email is valid and allowed by .net model validation's stack. i thought it was silently dropped for wrong email too, but it seems to be something else - database maybe?

Yes you need to add following code to allow apostrophe.
opt.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcd....zABCDE...Z0123456789-._@+'";
ASP.NET Core Identity uses UserValidator<TUser> to validate user names, and by default it disallow special characters.
Ensure you validate user input to prevent security risks like SQL injection and XSS attacks when accepting special characters in usernames.
